# Strange behavior causing reference to be set to null when calling ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm experiencing some extremely weird behavior when calling [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(v=VS.85).aspx) in C# through this P/Invoke signature:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
    int dwSize,
    out int lpNumberOfBytesRead
    );
```

---

In my application I'm scanning the entire memory of memory regions that have read and write access (and some more filters applied, that's another part though).

The code in the scanning part is something like this:

```
int numberOfBytes;
if (!NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(handle, region.StartAddress,
    buffer, (int)region.RegionSize, out numberOfBytes))
// The handle, region (custom struct containing some fields from the
// MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION struct), and buffer come from parameters.
```

And the code works perfectly. It scans the entire memory for a sequence of bytes. No problems there.

---

A bit further in my program's flow I have this code:
*Note: it's using the same handle IntPtr as the previous code (checked it) and it runs in the same thread*

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[128]; // In my real app this is some calculated value
                            // however that irrelevant. It's calculated 128.
if (!NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(handle, location.Location,
    buffer, buffer.Length, out bytesRead))
    continue; // Error while reading
// At this point buffer == null, so the next line causes an exception
if (bytesRead != buffer.Length) continue;
```

The code is very much alike, but for some reason the reference to buffer is lost and buffer is set to null. If it wouldn't be an external call I'd be 100% sure it's a bug, because buffer isn't passed as a `ref` or `out` parameter. However I know .NET does some vodoo stuff when it comes to external calls (marshaling for example).

What makes the situation even weirder is that when I replace that code with:

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
byte[] bufferRef = buffer;
if (!NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(handle, location.Location,
    buffer, buffer.Length, out bytesRead))
    continue; // Error while reading
buffer = bufferRef;
if (bytesRead != buffer.Length) continue;
```

The code simply works. Memory read and all! So all that happens is that for some reason the `buffer` variable loses it's reference to the actual buffer. And it confuses the hell out of me.

---

**Is this behavior a result of something I did wrong (such as a faulty P/Invoke), is it dangerous (leaking memory?), and explainable?**

---

My configuration:

- .NET Framework 4.0
- Visual Studio Professional 2012 (Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1)
- Installed .NET Framework 4.5.50709
- Running as administrator
- Occurs in both release and debug builds, both in the visual studio host executable and the regular build executable.
- Windows 7 64-bits
- Process I'm reading memory from is 32-bits
- Build configuration: Platform: Any CPU

---

**Edit:** The complete NativeMethods class I'm using can be found here: http://paste2.org/p/2770271

**Edit2:** I added the simple steps I followed to fix the problem as an answer which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14410443/613176).

Comment: A sidenote: Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns 1008, same code it returns at startup.

Comment: Your MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION declaration is wrong, RegionSize is an UIntPtr, not an ulong.  Not sure how that could corrupt the stack.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that pointed me in the direction of fixing the problem :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably since you are a 64-bit app, your lpNumberOfBytesRead should have been "long" and so the call to ReadProcessMemory overwrites (part of your) buffer pointer on return.

Comment: Where does it fail? On 64-bit, did you try changing your interop declaration to use long for the size read?

Comment: My complete native methods class can be found [here](http://paste2.org/p/2770271).

Comment: And yes my application is built with x64 in mind, however I'm reading memory from a x86 application. But for some reason `VirtualQueryEx` doesn't work then.

Comment: Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519452/int-vs-size-t-on-64bit.

Comment: Both VirtualQueryEx and ReadProcessMemory have arguments whose size depend on the platform - yours, that is - the bitness of the process you are reading from is irrelevant for this.

Comment: I've read the first link about a million times, there's no extra information in there. As to the second article, in .NET (or managed) I cannot use size_t, and can't `typedef` it depending on the platform. I'll try to port it to 32-bits completely.

Comment: You should be able to just use long in place of int when you're compiling for 64-bit.

Comment: Well, C# doesn't know a `LongPtr` only an `IntPtr`. So I cannot use long pointers without resorting to unsafe code. Which might in this case be the best approach. (Or treating pointers as value types, and simply using `int` and `long` instead of their managed pointer wrappers.)

Comment: I just rechecked the definitions of `VirtualQueryEx`, and they seem completely correct. (PS. I didn't downvote.)

Comment: Your ulong RegionSize is fine for 64-bit but that's probably why it fails in 32-bit where it should be 32-bits. (in MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)

Comment: Yes it was what caused it to fail. Both `RegionSize` and `dwLength` are of type `SIZE_T`, which is defined as: `unsigned __int64` on 64-bits and `unsigned long` on 32-bits. However `unsigned long` is only 32 bits in 32-bits instead of 64-bits which'd make a whole lot more sense to a C# programmer :P

Answer (score 0):

The `OutAttribute` of `byte[] lpBuffer` declared in your ReadProcessMemory import (which is the correct porting of `_Out_ LPVOID lpBuffer`) specifies that data should be marshaled from callee back to caller... so your byte array is probably being null referenced by the callee itself (Kernel32).

Comment: Why'd it be nulled by kernel32 when it's correctly filled with data AND it returns a nonzero value (or with other words, no error was raised)? Edit: It does marshal correctly though because all the data is available in the buffer (some code after that checks the data and it's validated correctly). So the read goes through correctly. And why *does* it work in the first code I provided but not in the second?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the process to the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: To Visual Studio's debugger yes, to OllyDbg debugger no, do you think that will help?

Comment: OllyDbg won't attach altogether (it gives some not supported error), most likely cause it's running under a VM.

Comment: You can use the VS JIT debugger. Just run your application from the assembly itself, let it crash... then when the exception is thrown a window should pop up asking you if you want to debug the application... do that.

Answer (score 0):

Due to tips from [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/) and [500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448932/) (whom I marked as accepted answer) I managed to solve the problem.

These are the steps I took:

1. I chose to use 32-bit instead of Any CPU. (Mostly for backwards compatibility.)
2. Then I updated the P/Invoke signatures using the MSDN pages for the functions and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) page about windows data types. And chose for the 32-bit variants of the signatures.
3. I ran the code again and the buffer reference wasn't cleared.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For what concerns 1), if I'm under x64 environment and I run yout code using 32-bit target platform I get exactly your error.

Comment: That's because I didn't post the fixed P/Invoke signatures. The ones in this topic are faulty, and they caused the issue (silently).

Answer (score -2):

Do not mark the `byte[] buffer` as an `[Out]` parameter. It's more akin to `ref` than `out`, which is already implied since it is a byte array. Since integers (`int` here) are a value-type, it needs the `out` parameter for `numberOfBytesRead`. That's the only one that should be marked with `out`.

When something is marked as an `out` parameter, the `Marshal` class expects the callee (`ReadProcessMemory` here) to supply a value back. A byte array is merely a pointer (address) to a location in memory where bytes are contained. You do not want this pointer to be written to by the callee.

Comment: `OutAttribute` is completely unrelated to `ref` and `out` parameter invoking. Besides that, your point about `int` (or I assume other value types) being the only parameters that should be marked `ref` or `out` is complete rubbish, there's many good designs where reference types are marked as such. The `OutAttribute` relates to marshaling and is required.

Comment: The `[OutAttribute]` is not completely unrelated. AFAIK `out` is synonymous with `[Out] ref`. You can say what you want, but I have written tons of code using `ReadProcessMemory` and the like via P/Invoke and never had them marked as `ref` or `[Out]` on the buffer. I have seen a lot of strange things happen with these functions (typically Win32 errors or zero reads) but not the buffer getting overwritten with `NULL`. I am trying to help you by pointing out things that are different than my working code.

Comment: That's because the VM uses different interop techniques that go beyond the default C# behavior. Like I said in my question, if this wasn't an external function I'd file it as a bug. `[Out]` however is **not** the same as `[Out] ref`. Ref and out parameters are a features of CIL and do not relate to the attribute that hints the VM  like the `OutAttribute` does. No matter how much the result of them are similar they're fundamentally different and it should not be taught that they're the same.

Comment: Here is a good resource: [MSDN: CLR Inside Out: Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx) Judging from the information there, `out` corresponds to `[OutAttribute]` and `ref` corresponds to `[InAttribute], [OutAttribute]`. There are some object types that have 'defaults' such as `StringBuilder` which defaults to `[In], [Out]` without you having to specify that. The point being that I doubt you need to pass `[Out]` for the `byte[]` type as it is actually a `byte*` behind the scenes which you do __NOT__ want the callee to change. (`out byte*` could translate to `byte**`)

Comment: That resource if you read it carefully only says that marshaling behavior is similar to those keywords, however it does **not** imply that they're the same, nor that they're even technically related. As to your argument about `byte[]` being `byte*` that too isn't true. Since the byte array is a reference types, not a pointer to. Even though at CPU level they may be treated the same, at language level they're fundamentally different. (And reference types are very useful for code security.)

Comment: I understand they are not identical but they are related. If you specify `ref` or `out`, it will trigger the `In` and `Out` hints for that parameter. Think about it, you are specifying `out int numberOfBytesRead` but there is no `[Out]` for it. Does that mean it will not be passed back out? Of course not, the `out` keyword implies that for you, they are related. Regardless of how C# abstracts `byte[]` for you, it must pass it as a `byte*` to native C methods. Considering it works without the `[Out]` attribute, it's not required and only adds potential for the pointer to be overwritten by Win32

Comment: I never said that `out` or `ref` aren't looked for when the marshaling stuff sees neither `OutAttribute` and `InAttribute`. The main reason for the attributes is have support across every language. For example VB.Net doesn't have `out`. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450200.aspx) that explains the correct signature of this P/Invoke call.